# Number in boxes of different sizes

Tags: combinatorics

Let us consider that I have $1,2,\ldots,\log n$ many numbers. I do the boxing of the numbers as follows. In the first box put $1$ only, in the second put $2$ elements ($2$ and $3$), in the third box put next $4$ elements $(4,5,6,7)$, so in the $i$th box put $2^{i}$ many elements. It is easy to verify that I need $\mathcal{O}(\log \log n)$ many boxes.

**Question :**  What will be the size of the last box in big Order terms or exactly?

I think it has to be $\mathcal{O}(\log \log n)$. But I don't have any idea how to prove it.

Comment: Is the 'size' of a box based on the number of elements or the sum of elements (e.g., in the third box you have $4, 5, 6, 7$.  So is the box size $4$ (elements); or size $22$ (sum of elements))?

Comment: @ paw88789 It is the number of elements in it. For third box the size is $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $\log n$ many numbers just consider $1, 2, 3 .., w$ different numbers. Numbers accommodated in first box = 1, second box = 2, third box = 4, ... so on. \begin{equation*}
\text{Numbers contained in $i$th box}: 2^{i-1}
\end{equation*} Lets assume you need B number of boxes. Using sum of a GP, 
\begin{gather*}
\text{Total Numbers accommodated} = \sum ^{B}_{i=1} 2^{i-1} =2^{B-1} -1=w\\
\Longrightarrow B\ =\ log( w+1) +1
\end{gather*}
Last Box is i=B, Hence size of the box will be,
\begin{equation*}
2^{B-1} =2^{\log( w+1) -1} =\frac{2^{\log( w+1)}}{2} =\frac{w+1}{2}
\end{equation*}

For the question asked, $w = \log(n)$ and Hence, the size of the last box will be $O(\log(n))$.